# Magento getCollection with website filter

Tags: magento

My Magento installation has the price scope set to website. Therefore I can set different product prices for different websites.

I am trying to load a product model but the price attribute value retrieved is the default value and not the website specific value.

Following is the code I am using.

```
             $oProduct = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")
                        ->getCollection()
                        ->addAttributeToSelect("*")
                        ->addWebsiteFilter($websiteId)
                        ->addFieldToFilter("entity_id", $ruleData["product_id"])                        
                        ->getFirstItem();
```

Not sure what I am missing the addWebsiteFilter method doesn't seem to have the desired effect.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to set the StoreId for the collection. So:

```
$oProduct = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")
                ->getCollection()
                ->setStoreId($correct_store_id_for_website)
                ->addAttributeToSelect("*")
                ->addFieldToFilter("entity_id", $ruleData["product_id"])                        
                ->getFirstItem();
```

Comment: Since I had the product id i modified slight the call to: $oProduct = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")
                        ->setStoreId($oStores[$websiteId])
                        ->load($ruleData["product_id"]);

Answer (score 6):

I wanted to apply a website filter on the frontend and found that using addWebsiteFilter()  (no parameter) to filter products by the current website accomplished this.
Example:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addWebsiteFilter()
```